# ActivityNotFoundException unable to find explicit activity class MediaProjectionPermissionActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaprojection

I have strange problem with `MediaProjectionManager`. Because general it works but on some device like HUAWEI Y560 i get this error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.media.MediaProjectionPermissionActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3794)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:46)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:74)
at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompatJB.java:31)
at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:163)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:935)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:1044)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:947)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:936)
at com.vyda.stream.fragments.streaming.preparation.BeforeScreencastFragment.startScreencastOrAskForPermission(BeforeScreencastFragment.java:112)
at com.vyda.stream.fragments.streaming.preparation.BeforeScreencastFragment$$ViewInjector$2.doClick(BeforeScreencastFragment$$ViewInjector.java:33)
at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4790)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19891)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Comment: Check if you have  added MediaProjectionPermissionActivity in the AndroidManfest.xml file or not

Comment: Have you added the activity declaration in the manifest?

Comment: I have `<activity
            android:name="com.android.systemui.MediaProjectionPermissionActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />` and still doesnt work :(

Comment: As you can see from its package that MediaProjectionPermissionActivity is an activity defined by the android system and not by your application. You are hitting this because those Huawei devices do not have that system activity for you to start projection. Why they don't have it? Security reasons?
 I don't know but since Android is open source and OEM's can choose what goes into their device, we can't question the absence of the same.

Comment: @Michael i am facing same issues in Lenovo/10 device.